# Повесить событие на кадр анимации

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли привязать событие(вызов функции скрипта) на определенный кадр в анимации?
Или как отловить этот кадр? (смена состояний не подходит)

Comment: добавил в ответ объяснение к вопросу `Или как отловить этот кадр` .....  возможно в будущем тоже будет полезно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Легко.

В анимации можно делать очень много вещей, в том числе и устанавливать различные события.

Например в скрипте есть метод:

```
public void PrintFloat(float someValue) {
    Debug.Log("Метод PrintFloat печатает значение: " + someValue);
}
```

В окне `Animation` можете добавить событие анимации к клипу в текущей позиции воспроизведения, нажав кнопку Event или в любой момент анимации, дважды щелкнув на строке событий (Event Line) в точке, где вы хотите добавить триггер события:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда вы добавляете событие, показывается диалоговое окно для указания имени функции и значения параметра, который вы хотите передать ей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавленные к клипу события в строке событий показываются в виде маркеров. Удержание мыши над маркером показывает подсказку с именем функции и значением параметра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Happy end!

---

Теперь про другой пункт из вопроса (или второй способ):

> Или как отловить этот кадр?

В теории можно узнать сколько всего фреймов будет идти клип. Формула такова:

```
int totalFrames = (int)Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Floor((fps * animationClip.length) / animationSpeed));
```

В данной формуле переменные:

- fps — количество сменяемых кадров за единицу времени. В теории можно поставить константное значение равное 60. Но это не точно
- animationClip.length — длина клипа в секундах, где `animationClip` имеет тип [AnimationClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.html)
- animationSpeed — скорость анимации. Значение типа `float`. Анимация в нормальном состоянии имеет значение 1. Больше значение — больше скорость.

Далее, зная, что метод `Update` вызывается 60 кадров в секунду (опять же в теории), значит можно поставить счетчик, который считает от 1 до `totalFrames` кадров анимации и  в нужный момент (например если счетчик между 5 и 6 кадрами анимации) дернуть триггер (метод) у любого скрипта любого объекта.